# self.window setRootViewController not working on xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am facing some issues w.r.t XCode 6.1.1 , here is my code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[DBManager getSharedInstance] initWithdbFile];
    [[DBManager getSharedInstance] createtableScripts];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    containerViewController =[[CprViewController alloc] init];
    [containerViewController Setup];
    [self.window setRootViewController:containerViewController.containerViewController];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self pickModel];
    return YES;
}
```

Now the app works fine in older XCode i.e 5.1.1 but while simulating on XCode 6.1.1 the app launches the Launch image and there is no response i.e the execution ends at      [self.window setRootViewController:containerViewController.containerViewController]; and it doesnt proceed to execute further lines of code. It shows no error in console. (The app however runs on device having latest OS (i.e iOS 8).  Please help.

*Edited Post -- begins here

Thanks for helping out. Here’s the problem that i am facing,
This is in my AppDelegate file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{  
    [[DBManager getSharedInstance] initWithdbFile];
    [[DBManager getSharedInstance] createtableScripts];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];  //Now Removed!!!
    containerViewController =[[CprViewController alloc] init];
    [containerViewController Setup];
    self.window.rootViewController = containerViewController.containerViewController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//Now Removed!!!
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];//Now Removed!!!
    [self pickModel];
    return YES;
}
```

Now i have removed the three lines just as you suggested and now the execution continues

Now this is my code for [containerViewController Setup];

```
-(void)Setup
{
     SideMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController = [SideMenuViewController  homeBookViewController];
    CprStartPageViewController *accounts=[[CprStartPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CprStartPageViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navController= [[CprNavigationViewController alloc]
                         initWithRootViewController:accounts];
    self.containerViewController = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController                                                 containerWithCenterViewController:self.navController leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
       rightMenuViewController:nil];
    [leftMenuViewController.passBookTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:0];
}
```

The above code attaches a side menu (here i am attaching a left side menu) - No error in this code i.e the execution continues.
Now CprLoginViewController is my parentViewController 
i.e the parentViewController for the 4 screen that i had mentioned and this is my initWithNibName for the 4 screens

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil parentViewController:(CprLoginViewController*) inVC
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil parentViewController:inVC];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

and the error now occurs in CprLoginViewController where i am using a procedure called showNextPage to navigate between these 4 pages

```
-(void) showNextPage
{
    if (currentPage > numberPages)
        return;
    CprLoginSubViewController *controller;
        switch(currentPage)
        {
            case 0:
                controller = [[Corppersondtl alloc] initWithNibName:@"Corppersondtl" bundle:nil parentViewController:self];
                break;
            case 1:
                controller = [[CprLoginSub1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CprLoginSub1ViewController" bundle:nil parentViewController:self];
                break;
            case 2:
                controller = [[CprLoginSub2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CprLoginSub2ViewController" bundle:nil parentViewController:self];
                break;
            case 3:
                controller = [[CprLoginSub3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CprLoginSub3ViewController" bundle:nil parentViewController:self];
                break;
            case 4:
                controller = [[CprLoginSub4ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CprLoginSub4ViewController" bundle:nil parentViewController:self];
            default:
                break;
        }
    CGRect rBounds;
    // add the required controller's view to scroll view
    if (controller.view.superview == nil)
    {
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(frame) * (currentPage);
        frame.origin.y = 0; 
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [self addChildViewController:controller];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
        [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        // just scroll to appropriate page
        rBounds = self.scrollView.bounds;
        rBounds.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(rBounds) * currentPage;
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:rBounds animated:YES];
    }
    NSLog(@"scrollView is %lf", self.scrollView.frame.origin.y);
    viewOriginalbounds = rBounds; //self.scrollView.frame;
    currentPage++;
}
```

In the above code i am attaching a scrollview to scroll the screen upwards when keyboard appears for text inputs.
Now the line if (controller.view.superview == nil) is throwing exc_bad_access error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete that lines of code

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: @MatthiasBauch there is no need to create window, system already handles that itself

Comment: @Azat thank you sir, that worked, but now i am facing another issue, further i am adding a scroll view (apologies for not properly formatting the code) if (controller.view.superview == nil) now this is throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. controller is a UIViewController and i am loading my viewcontrollers into the controller variable (i have 4 screens which require scroll view)

Comment: @GMAN could you post some more code please? Specifically that one which causes crash, i.e. after commenting which lines of code other stuff works fine